# use one() within a for loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    if (res[i] != 'a' && res[i] != '-b') {

    } else {
        // alert will triger multiple times here
        alert();
    }

}
```

I loop through an array to check something, how can I run once in the else statement? if I put a function there, it will trigger multiple times.

Comment: Don't forget to indent your code correctly. It makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: *"use one() within a for loop jquery"* There's no `one` call in your question, nor any other use of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to indicate whether the else block was executed, if so don't execute it again

```
var run = true;
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    if (res[i] != 'a' && res[i] != '-b') {

    } else if (run) {
        // alert will triger multiple times here
        alert();
        run = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: shouldn't be it `run=false` ? in else branch

Answer (score 2):

You need to [break;](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) after your else-action.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    if (res[i] != 'a' && res[i] != '-b') {

    } else {
        // alert will triger multiple times here
        alert();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: may not be the same as rest of the `res` will not get processed if you break... ie if there is any other value other than `a` or `-b` in the loop after the first `a` or `-b` element

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple boolean flag:

```
// Introduce the flag before your for loop
var process = true;
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    if (res[i] != 'a' && res[i] != '-b') {

    } else if(process) {
        // alert will triger multiple times here
        alert();
        process = false; // Reset the process flag
    }

}
```